# Youtube in flyperlink

Tags: applications, browser, youtube

I recently came across a beautiful web browser named Flyperlink.  It's really good but only problem with this browser is whenever i open a youtube link in it, it opens youtube app instead. Is there any way to open youtube on flyperlink.

Comment: Have you checked if Youtube is the default app for those links? Please go to **Settings > Apps > Youtube** and check its default actions. If you can remove the default action then you should get a dialogue option prompting you to choose in which app youtube links should be opened

Comment: No,  it's not default. I've even tried after uninstalling youtube app but then flyperlink opens the link in secondary browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Apps -> YouTube -> Clear Defaults.

Next time you open a you tube link, you will be asked to Chose which app should be used to open the link. You can chose Flyperlink from there.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've tried this already.